# Parsing through all textfiles in folder, saving text surrounding a regexp search

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a code that iterates through all textfiles in a directory, parses them while searching for the occurence of certain regular expressions, and saving the preceding and following 20 or so words.

I use dir.glob to select all .txt files, then want to loop a code (each do) for all these textfiles, use a regular expression to search for the occurence of a word (line.match? File.find_all? , and then print the word and a selection around it to a base file.

I am trying to puzzle it all together, but I don't believe I'm getting very far nor any further. Any help is much appreciated.

This is what I have:

```
    Dir::mkdir("summaries") unless File.exists?("summaries")
    Dir.chdir("summaries")
    all_text_files = Dir.glob("*.txt")

    all_text_files.each do |textfile|
        puts "currently summarizing " + textfile + "..."
        File.readlines(#{textfile}, "r").each do |line|
            if line.match /trail/ #does line.match work?
            if line =~ /trail/ #would this work?
                return true
                #save line to base textfile while referencing name of searchfile
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will go through each .txt file in the directory and print all the occurances of whatever regular expression you decide on to the `base.txt` file along with the name of the file it was found in. I chose to use the `scan` method which is another regex method available that will return an array of matching results. See [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) for the rubydoc on scan. You can also change the code around if you only want one occurrance in each file.

```
##
# This method takes a string, int and string as an argument.
# The method will return the indices that are padded on either side
# of the passed in index by 20 (in our case) but not padded by more
# then the size of the passed in text. The word parameter is used to
# decide the top index as we do not want to include the word in our
# padding calculation. 
#
# = Example
#
#  indices("hello bob how are you?", 5, "bob") 
#      # => [0, 13] since the text length is less than 40
#
#  indices("this is a string of text that is long enough for a good example", 31, "is")
#      # => [11, 53] The extra 2 account for the length of the word 'is'.
#    
    def indices text, index, word
    #here's where you get the text from around the word you are interested in.
    #I have set the padding to 20 but you can change that as you see fit.
    padding = 20
    #Here we are getting the lowest point at which we can retrieve a substring.
    #We don't want to try and get an index before the beginning of our string.
    bottom_i = index - padding < 0 ? 0 : index - padding

    #Same concept as bottom except at the top end of the string.
    top_i = index + word.length + padding > text.length ? text.length : index + word.length + padding
    return bottom_i, top_i
end

#Script start.
base_text = File.open("base.txt", 'w')
Dir::mkdir("summaries") unless File.exists?("summaries")
Dir.chdir("summaries")

Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |textfile|
    whole_file = File.open(textfile, 'r').read
    puts "Currently summarizing " + textfile + "..."
    #This is a placeholder for the 'current' index we are looking at.
    curr_i = 0
    str = nil
    #This will go through the entire file and find each occurance of the specified regex. 
    whole_file.scan(/trail/).each do |match|
      #This is the index of the matching string looking from the curr_i index onward.
      #We do this so that we don't find and report things twice.
      if i_match = whole_file.index(match, curr_i)
        top_bottom = indices(whole_file, i_match, match)
        base_text.puts(whole_file[top_bottom[0]..top_bottom[1]] + " : " + File.path(textfile))
        #We set our current index to be the index at which we found the match so when
        #we ask for the matching index from curr_i onward, we don't get the same index
        #again.
        curr_i += i_match         
        #If you only want one occurrance break here            
      end
    end
    puts "Done summarizing " + textfile + "."
end
base_text.close
```

Comment: Wow, that is effin amazing. Magic. Thanks Nattydubs(!!).

Comment: However, I'd love to understand a bit more it. Could you explain some of the code? (everything concerning i for example)

Comment: Sure let me add some more comments to the example and let me know what else I can elaborate on after that point.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing: would you know how to add multiple search terms (for example: /trail/  AND /another/ AND /third/) ?

Comment: You could wrap everything in a method that accepts a search term and then call it for each term. This would have more file IO as you would be opening each file three times (given three search terms). There are quite a few refactorings that you could do to the example to make it more modular and then add multiple terms.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand close to everything from script_start, but the Helper remains abracadabra to me. I get what it does, but not how it works..

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks very sloppy. It's full of mistakes. Here are a few (there may be more):

You're missing a `+` here:

```
puts "currently summarizing " textfile + "..."
```

It should be:

```
puts "currently summarizing " + textfile + "..."
```

You can only use `#{}` inside double quotes, so instead of:

```
File.open(#{textfile}, "r")
```

just do:

```
File.open(textfile, "r")
```

This doesn't make any sense at all:

```
File.open(#{textfile}, "r")
textfile.each do line
```

It should be:

```
File.open(textfile, "r").each do |line|
```

This doesn't make sense either:

```
return true
print line
```

`line` will never be printed right after `return true`.

Edit:

As for your new question: either works, but [`match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-match) and [`=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) have different return values. It depends on what you want to do exactly.

```
foo = "foo trail bar"
foo.match /trail/ # => #<MatchData "trail">
foo =~ /trail/ # => 4
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please try to understand any error messages you get. You should be able to detect these kinds of mistakes by understanding the errors you get. Good luck.